# MessageBox doesnt appear when eclipse plugin has been deployed?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have written an Eclipse plugin and I have added option for help in Eclipse "Help" menu. On click of that help the MessageBox appears.

This MessageBox appears when i run or debug by Eclipse application however when i deploy this plugin on other PC and click help the MessageBox doesnt appear.

This is my code:

```java
public class MyHelp implements IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate {

    public void run(IAction arg0) {

        try {

        String message = "This is demo data";

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MessageBox box = new MessageBox(new Shell(), SWT.OK);
        box.setMessage(message);
        box.setText("Help title");
        box.open();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this one ..?

For help I have added an ActionSet in my plugin as :

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
      <actionSet
            id="com.my.plugin.actionSet"
            label="My ActionSet"
            visible="true">
         <menu
               id="mymenu"
               label="My Menu" 
               path="help/helpStart">
            <groupMarker
                  name="start">
            </groupMarker>
            <separator
                  name="additions">
            </separator>
         </menu>
         <action
               class="com.myexample.MyHelp"
               id="MyHelp"
               label="Use Help"
               icon="icons/plugin_help.png"
               menubarPath="help/mymenu/start"
               style="push">
         </action>
        </actionSet>
   </extension>
```

Do I need to do anything else ?

Comment: How do you deploy a plugin to another PC?

Comment: Are there any warnings/other outputs on the console when debugging (where it works)? You could also try to run an eclipse instance from a command line (after deployment) and see if any Errors are displayed when you try to open the dialog.

Comment: @AlexanderGavrilov: I exported my plugin as jar from plugin.xml and copied in plugin folder of eclipse..

Comment: @Cedric : When i debug application it works... but when i deploy it as plugin in plugin folder it fails... and can you tell me how to run plugin from command line..

Comment: Well, I'd just install it on an eclipse instance and run this one from command line. Open a command line, navigate to your eclipse directory and execute it. In Windows' cmd for example do `cd C:\path\to\eclipse`, then type `eclipse.exe`, I'm not sure for other OS...

Answer (score 0):

If you are running eclipse >= 3.3 then you may drop it to plugins folder. Also, try to restart your eclipse with `-clean option`.

I'd suggest you to user dropins folder for manual installation. Please, refer to the documentation: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Dropins

**Upd1:**
In order to run your code I had to add some unimplemented methods (I am using eclipse version 3.6):

```
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IAction;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate;

public class MyHelp implements IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate {

    public void run(final IAction arg0) {

        final String message = "This is demo data";

      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final MessageBox box = new MessageBox(new Shell(), SWT.OK);
        box.setMessage(message);
        box.setText("Help title");
        box.open();

   }

    public void selectionChanged(final IAction action, final ISelection selection) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void init(final IWorkbenchWindow window) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Also, check your plugin MANIFEST to have following line: 
`Bundle-SymbolicName: your_plugin_id;singleton:=true`
I've just copied plugin from the workspace into the dropins folder of my eclipse instance and it was working out of the box.

Are you sure, that plugin manifest is in the jar file? Check out the Bin tab or build.properties to be sure, that everything is exported correctly.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have already added -clean in my .ini
Let me try by dropping it into droppins... However whats the main difference of deploying it in plugins folder and droppin folder

Comment: "A subtle twist on old behavior here is that plug-ins and features added to the dropins folder are properly installed into the system rather than being forced in.". Try setting -clean as a launch property of your eclipse.exe process (right click on eclipse.exe - properties, then after your_parth_to_exlipse/eclipse.exe add -clean).

Comment: that did not work :( ..
should i change any code such as implementing interface or anything ?

Comment: Well, this is weird. Since I've just tried to create your plugin and placed it into the dropins folder and run my local eclipse and plugin was there. Thou, I had to perform a slight modification of your class (since it wasn't even compiled. Please see code in the answer above). What version of eclipse do you use? Is it the same as the version on other PC? If you deploy it to the eclipse, which you are using for development will it work?

Comment: I created plugin jar using export wizard and dropped plugin jar in my droppins folder.. Other option of plugin work such as popmenus... however help option i provided not working... I am using Eclipse indigo and juno.

Comment: I have same code as above :-/
I have just not used final keyword.

Comment: Try to just copy plugin folder, not jar file into dropins.

Comment: nothing working ... in debug and run mode working but not when deployed